# Possible to 'view next option' when pressing K to go to VimHelp

Tags: vim

Let's take the following scenario:

I have the following line of text:

```
set number
```

I want to look up what `number` does in the help section, so I place my cursor over it:

```
set |number
```

And press `K`. Easy enough. However, about 30% of the time it will go to the 'wrong section', based on vim's best guess. For example, for this one it takes me to:

[image]

Is there a way to, for example, go to the 'next match' in vim's guesstimate straight from the help section? Or do I have to either Google this or type in `:h number<ctrl-D>` to see what other options it might be in:

[image]

Comment: As it's an option then the topic is surely called `:h 'number'`. No need to guess.

Comment: @Matt sure, but is there a way once I'm already on the help page, to view or goto the next similar option?

Comment: But what is "similar"? There's `:h :helpgrep` but for sure it'll give too much unrelated links for the word "number".

Comment: Or you can use autocompletion like `:h number<tab>` to search for similar topics.

Comment: @Matt -- I see, so maybe I should just map something like `ctrl-K` to `:h expand<cword><tab>` ?